# fgetcsv / fopen in reverse

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I am trying to do this exact function, only want to be able to display the last 20 lines of the document?

```
    $file = fopen("/tmp/$importedFile.csv","r");
    while ($line =  fgetcsv($file))
    {
        $i++;
        $body_data['csv_preview'][] = $line;
        if ($i > 20) break;
    }
    fclose($file);
```

I have tried changing the  `"r"` in `$file = fopen("/tmp/$importedFile.csv","r");`however it seems there is only variations of where to put the pointer with read and write.

I feel this could be an easy one. my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use an [`SqlFileObject`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php). First, you need to know how many lines are in the file, which you can calculate like this:

```
$filename = "/tmp/$importedFile.csv";

// Create a new object for the file
$file = new SplFileObject( $filename, "r");

$lines = 0;
while ( !$file->eof()) {
   $file->fgets();
   $lines++;
}
```

Now you know there are `$lines` number of lines in the file. Then, you have to seek to the `$lines - 20` line number, and read your CSV data until EOF, like this:

```
$file->seek( $lines - 20);
while ( !$file->eof()) { 
    $body_data['csv_preview'][] = $file->fgetcsv();
}
```

Perhaps there is a more efficient way to calculate `$lines`. Also, you should confirm that there is more than 20 lines in the file before attempting to `seek()` to `$lines - 20`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code returns first 20 lines. Try modify it for last 20 lines

```
if($i > 20)
   array_shift($body_data['csv_preview'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this:

```
$file = fopen("/tmp/$importedFile.csv","r");
$start = count( file( $file ) ) - 20;
$i = 0;
while ($line =  fgetcsv($file)) {
    $i++;
    if ( $i > $start ) $body_data['csv_preview'][] = $line;
}
fclose($file);
//Body_data has now the last 20 lines.
```

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 (never used that file() function) but you could further simplify that a lot by just reading the 20 last elements from the array produced by `file( $file )` and then use `str_getcsv` to parse the lines, no need to reread the file. The only potential downside is the memory it will consume when massive csv files need to be read.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way

```
$fileend = array();
$file = fopen("/tmp/$importedFile.csv","r");
while ($line =  fgetcsv($file))
{
    // we have a line, so if $fileend already contains the required number
    // of lines we have to make some room.
    if (count($fileend) > 20) {
        $fileend=array_shift($fileend);
    }
    // add freshly read line to array's end
    array_push($fileend,$line);
}
fclose($file);
// at this point $fileend will contain the 20 last lines of the file.
```

I can't guarantee you that it will be blindingly fast though...

A muich faster way would be to store the lines in a fixed-size circular buffer, which is easier than it sounds

```
$i=0;
while ($line =  fgetcsv($file))
{
    // store as linenumber modulo 20 'th element in array
    $circularbuffer[$i % 20] = $line;
    $i++;
}
```

And then to read it

```
// must start reading after last written element, $i has the correct value.
// and we will read 20 times - same modulo calculation to "circulate" buffer
for ($j=$i;$j<$i+20;$j++) {
    $body_data['csv_preview'][] = $circularbuffer[$j%20];
}
```

Obviously the big advantage here is that you read the file only once, and I think that the read operation is by far the costliest (in execution time) part of the function.